# Laravel Eloquent Chat Inbox Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I keep trying to ask this question here on stackoverflow several times but cant seem to get any help. Maybe third time is the charm.

I'm building a chat feature inside laravel app and I'm struggling to get the inbox section right. I've read a tonn of other threads on here but mysql is not my strongest suit so I'm having an issue.

Basically, I got this query to get me the last message from the user who just messaged me to show up in my inbox. The problem is, if I'm the one sending out a message to another user, it will not display anything in my inbox since I'm the author not the recipient. How would I make this query to display the latest message from another user in my inbox and also show that I have started a conversation to another user.

```
 $chat_inbox = Message::where('author_id', $this->user->id)
        ->orWhere('recipient_id', $this->user->id)
            ->join(DB::raw('(Select max(id) as id from messages where author_id ='.$this->user->id.' group by unique_chat_id) LatestMessage'), function($join) {
                $join->on('messages.id', '=', 'LatestMessage.id');
            })
            ->get();
```

Mysql table columns are: unique_chat_id, author_id, recipient_id, viewed, user_read, created_at, and updated_at

If you need any further details, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Here is what my Message model looks like:

```
 class Message extends Model {

    protected $table = 'messages';
    protected $fillable = [
      'unique_chat_id',
      'author_id',
      'recipient_id',
      'message',
      'viewed',
      'user_read',

    ];

 }
```

Comment: so basically you wish to get the latest message both received and sent? perhaps elaborating more on what is `Message`, `Chat`, and any models will help.. it's a bit unclear..  `->on('messages.id', '=', 'LatestMessage.id')`

Comment: Are you trying to get all the messages you sent to other users and all the messages users sent to you? if that's the case try `Message::where('author_id', auth()->user()->id)->orWhere('recipient_id', auth()->user()->id)->get()`

Comment: Yes, but if you are the one sending the message, then I will display in inbox that a conversation has started. Just like any other chat inbox

Comment: @AfikDeri, that will return all of the messages from that conversation, I need to only the the last message and group it by the unique chat id.

Comment: @max234435 so if you'r looking for the last message replace `->get()` with `->latest()->first()`

Comment: @AfikDeri I don't think you understood me correctly. The sql statement that I have above already gives me the latest message for all conversations that I have going on in the chat. The problem I have is when I am the one who initiates a conversation to another user, It will not show in inbox since this particular sql query does not pick it up. And I don't have enough SQL knowledge to tweek it.

Comment: @max234435 If you are the one initiated the conversation you should receive the message since you are the author_id, if you have other logic in there let me know because it should work.